# Binding layout properties of different UserControls

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-interface, layout, element-binding

I have the following layout for a screen displaying multi-channel information (similar to audio tracks):

1. `MultiChannelPlotterControl` contains one `HorizontalRuler` instance at the bottom and a `UniformGrid` containing N `SingleChannelPlotterControl` instances;
2. Each `SingleChannelPlotterControl` has one instance of `VerticalRuler` aligned to left;

[image]

Problems are:

1. Each vertical ruler can have a different Width, but I would like them all to stretch to the largest width so that they could fit, but since they are on different controls, I cannot put them in the same container (another `UniformGrid`, for example. Now if I decide to put them together in a different container, they would not be part of the `SingleChannelPlotterControl` anymore;
2. There is a rectangular region on the bottom left corner. That is supposed to have the same Width of the VerticalRuler(s), but it is still higher in the layout tree. It is currently empty, but I could put something there and bind its Width, for example;

So the question is:

> How could I Layout/Element-Bind/Style these controls so that right edge of the Vertical Rulers keep aligned to each other (fitting the widest one) *and* with the left edge of the Horizontal Ruler?

EDIT:
I guess I could create a "LeftPanelWidth" DependencyProperty on `MultiChannelPlotterControl`, and on its getter use some `VisualTreeHelper` wizardry to get ActualWidths for every VerticalRuler inside, but how would I choose the largest width *and set the widths* of the others?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use SharedSizeGroup property on your column definition. You'll have to set IsSharedSizeScope=True on the correct parent container.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't have a column definition. The container of the SingleChannelPlotter controls is a UniformGrid with a single column. Each SingleChannelPlotter control's LayoutRoot is a DockPanel whose first child is a VerticalRuler control. Thus, each VerticalRuler has its own Width and is unaware of the existence of their "siblings". What I want is exactely a way to bind them all together to get the _visual effect_ of a column.

Comment: Then maybe the easiest way would be to replace your DockPanel with a Grid (you should be able to get the exact same layout). Then you'll be able to define the first column with a SharedSizeGroup. If you want more help, just paste your xaml code so I can help you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the problem by eliminating `SingleChannelPlotterControl` class.

Instead, I use two side-by-side `UniformGrid` instances (as the `ItemsPanel` of two `ItemsControl` instances), setting their `ItemsSource` to the same `CollectionViewSource` declared in XAML.

Then, for each `ItemsControl` I declare a different `ItemTemplate`, the left one containing a `VerticalRuler`, and the other one displaying the signals the same way `SingleChannelPlotterControl` was doing previously - except it doesn't contain the ruler anymore.